# Create a grid of divs from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create what is essentially a 7x3 grid from an array of letters. I want to be able to manipulate the opacity of the letters in each cell of the grid. I have attached a diagram at the bottom better illustrate this. Currently I'm having a problem appending the letters to any of the rows after the first row, knowing how to rectify this problem would also give me the knowledge to create a random selector but I can't work out what is wrong. I'm a novice at Javascript so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

edit: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy5Luke5/3/)

JS

```
var $grid = $('#grid-cnt'),
    rows = 3,
    gridH = $grid.height(),
    cellH = gridH/rows;

var gridArray = [
    ['C'],
    ['O'],
    ['M'],
    ['P'],
    ['A'],
    ['C'],
    ['T'],
];

for (var col = 0; col < gridArray.length; ++col){
   var $column = $('<div class="column">');

   $column.attr('col', col)
   for (var row = 0; row < rows; ++row){
       var $cell = $('<div class="cell">');

       $cell.attr('row', row);
       // $cell.css('width', cellW);
       $cell.css('height', cellH);
       $column.append($cell);
       $cell.append(gridArray[col][row]);
   }
  $grid.append($column)
};

$(document).on("click", function() {
    var columnselector = Math.floor((Math.random() * gridArray.length));
    // Random row selector
    var rowselector = Math.floor((Math.random() * gridArray[0].length));
    //hide random letter from 2D array
       //select random cell from column and addClass hidden


}
```

CSS

```
#grid {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.cell {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[image: mock-up]

Comment: Can you fix the syntax errors as a first step?

Comment: What do the pictures represent? One is your current output, and one is the desired output, perhaps? Which is which?

Comment: Why not use `display: grid`?

Comment: I apologise. I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy5Luke5/2/) without the syntax error.

Comment: The first image illustrates the grid, the second illustrates manipulating a cells opacity. I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy5Luke5/2/) with my current output

Comment: You have `gridArray[col][row]` but what happens when col = 3 and row = 2?  There is no corresponding value in that array, `gridArray[3][2]`.  (That's why it fails when row!=0)

Comment: Also, be very careful because you have the `col` as the first index and `row` as second index.  It makes sense given what you are trying to do but that is exactly reversed from how you normally look at multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @nurdyguy Thanks for replying. I realise the problem now.